# Simulate emitted "Socket hang up" in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, error-handling, dom-events

I would like to simulate an emitted "Socket hang up error" by implementing a simple faulty server request/response scenario.

Here is a simple faulty server scenario using the native [http](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) module. The `makeRequest` function emits the `Socket hang up` error.

```
var server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  console.log('got request');
  res.write('efgh')
  res.end();
});

server.listen(8080, function() {
  makeRequest(() => {
    server.close();
  });
});

function makeRequest(cb) {
  var req = http.request('http://localhost:8080', function(res) {
    console.log('got response')
    res.resume();
    cb();
  })
  req.write('abcd');
}
```

Any suggestions on how to simulate emitting this error and so I can handle it in the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module pattern below? The ultimate test is running the code block below and verifying that by catching the **emitted** `Socket hang up` error, the `pipe` commands will not execute and fail:

```
request('https://localhost:8080/doodles.zip')
    .on('error', function(error){ 
        console.log('error requesting base zip file '); 
        console.log(error);
    })
    .on('data', function(chunk){
        console.log('A new chunk: ', chunk);
    })
    .on('end', function(){
        // console.log(output);
        console.log('End GET Request');    
    })    
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('doodles.txt'))
        .on('error',function(error){

            console.log('error streaming base zip file');
            console.log(error);

        })
        .on('close',function(){
            console.log('on close of zip pipe to txt');
        });
```

Comment: its not clear what is your test framework. mock etc

Answer (score 0):

From the docs: https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/blob/ba048e72b02e17f0c73e0dcb7d37e76a03327c5a/lib/_http_client.js#L164 
I Hope this is what you meant. Good Luck

```
function createHangUpError() {
  var error = new Error('socket hang up');
  error.code = 'ECONNRESET';
  return error;
}
```